# Is it possible to have a MySQL table comment defined before its create statement?

Tags: mysql, create-table, comments

In order to document SQL code in a more linear fashion, I wanted to make appear the description of a table that is going to be created before the creation statement. So my first idea was to put that in a user-defined variable with which I could fill the comment instruction, but it seems to be unsupported (at least in the 5.6 version I have to deal with):

```
set @description = 'The following table is a useless dummy test.';
drop table if exists `test`;
create table `test` (dummy int) comment @test; -- syntax error
show table status where name='test';
```

Is there an other way to achieve the initial goal? Of course it's always possible to use `--` SQL comments before the creation statement, but then it wouldn't appear in the recorded database structure, or at the price of a awful duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't match the question, here is a solution to its underlying problem: having the description of a table directly next to it's creation statement.

The MySQL syntax require to put the comment attached to the table at the end, but if the table have many fields, each declared on one or several lines, then the table comment can quickly be sent of sight of its declaration start.

Now, one can easily create a table with it's comment as sole attached statement, then alter it to include fields it should contains.

```
CREATE TALBE `test` COMMENT 'Informative description';
ALTER TABLE test
  ADD id
    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    COMMENT 'Description of the id field',
  ADD data
    BLOB
    COMMENT 'Description of the data field',
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to do this using dynamic SQL:

```
SET @description = 'The following table is a useless dummy test.';
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE test (dummy int) COMMENT=''', @description, '''');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note that each prepared statement is precisely just that; a single statement.  So, to do this from the command line, you might need 3 statements to cover the full logic you want to run.

Comment: Seems a possible solution, indeed, thank you. I would prefer something more readable, and on that regard even my initial idea didn't meet my expectation, I have to admit. So thank you Tim, I'll validate the solution if no one come with an even shiniest solution in the coming days.